# sql query to insert received parameters from user, and Get records from a existing table and insert into another existing table

Tags: sql-server

Anyone please help me

Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER procedure ExistingBook
   @title nvarchar(50),
   @Author  nvarchar(50),
   @Number  nvarchar(50)
as
   declare @Sno as int 

   begin
      if exists(select * from Students where Title = @title)
      begin
         select @Sno = count(*)
         from Teacher

         if (@Author='proof')
            if (@Number>'20')
               insert into Teacher(@Sno+1, Team, @title, getdate(), 
                                   @Number, PMName, Comments, ISBN, null, null)

         select
            Team, PMName, Comments, ISBN
         from Students
         where Title = @title  
       end
   end
```

When I execute the above query I get error

> The name "Team" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

I knew the reason for the above query

I tried in different way my query execute but records duplicated

Please some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert query is not formed correctly.

I think you want something like

```
    INSERT INTO Teacher
            (
             col1, 
             col2,
             col3,
             col4,
             col5,
             col6,
             col7,
             col8,
             col9
            )
            select
            @Sno+1,
            Team, 
            @title,
            @Number,
            PMName,
            Comments,
            ISBN,
             null,
             null
            from Students
where Title=@title
```

Comment: .... since those are all either literals, constants or SQL variables, you could **also** use `INSERT INTO dbo.Teacher(col1, ..., colN) VALUES (.......)`